# JQuery UI - Select specific tabs dynamically

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui-tabs

I want to develop an entirely ajax backend for a website I'm developing, and I'm looking at using jQuery UI. The tabs widget looks like it could be useful for my menu, however, I want to know if there's a way to load a specific tab dynamically. So basically, if someone entered the URL mysite.com/tab1 it would open the first tab, and tab2 would open the second etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: You want to load content via AJAX, or when someone visits a URL you want that a specific tab to default as the open one?

Comment: Ahh! what you are looking for is called **Hijax** http://domscripting.com/blog/display/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

There is no reason why it should not work! ;-)

> Ahh! what you are looking for is
>   called [**Hijax**](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/41) with support for
>   the **browser's back/forward navigation**
>   buttons and bookmarking. Enhance
>   comparable DHTML driven links as well.

try this:

> History/Remote - jQuery plugin
>   solution for hijaxing links and
>   enabling history
>   - http://stilbuero.de/jquery/history/index.html

And also read this:

> - [jQuery UI Tabs back button history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813601/jquery-ui-tabs-back-button-history)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a  name property on the tab link ( like so `<a name="tab-1" > </a>` and then  yoursite.com/#tab-1  it will activate your tab :)