# jQuery UI Tabs AJAX link with anchor

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to implement something quite simple, I want to have a tab menu, with submenu as anchor in tabs, let say :

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="file1.html">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="file1.html#anchor1">Et perditur</a></li>             
      <li><a href="file1.html#anchor2">Proin elit arcu</a></li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="file2.html">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="file3.html">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can easily switch tabs on the top level , but any attempts to access the file#anchor link failed, the best I could do was to actually open the right tab, but not go to the anchor.

Any hint ? Working example ?

Comment: Did you found how to do that? I'm looking at almost same problem, but can't find any solution (need remote tabs with anchor).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3330919/1285020

Here's an example using jquery address plugin http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/tabs/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.